# What is the best approach for learning the relationship of two dataframes affecting values of a given list?

Tags: python, algorithm, pandas, dataframe, deep-learning

I have a the following dataset of pandas dataframes:

A:

```
   col1  col2
0     5     3
1     5     4
```

B:

```
   col1  col2
0     6     4
1     2     4
```

my_list:

```
[24.5, 65.4]
```

Assume I have a dataset of thirty A,B,my_list pairs which have different sets of values. Changing a single or multiple values in either or both of the dataframes A and B affect the values in my_list.

Provided that I want to achieve [65.0, 46.21] in my_list, I need to find out what values need to be present in A,B dataframes.

I am looking for suggestions what would be the best solution to this problem? A simple ML algorithm? A deep learning model? If so, which one should I be using?

Please note that my dataset is small as 30 and I am looking to achieve a value as close as possible to the desired my_list value.

Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Just missing desired output...

Comment: @U9-Forward My desired output is `my_list = [65.0, 46.21]`

Comment: One that works?

Comment: @wwii what do you mean? I don't follow.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need a **regression** algorithm.

May I translate your task to: given 8 positional inputs, find a general formula, that produces the output closest to the desired output. This is a typical regression problem and you have many powerful tools you can use.

Given that your dataset is small, you'd better start with simple algorithms such as linear regression, then move to more complicated ones such as support vector machines if necessary.

Comment: they are not positional inputs, simple integers.

Comment: @sshussain270 but they are at specific positions right